# How to make an interactive python grid with tkinter and excel

Tags: python, excel, tkinter

I want to know how to create a grid that connects to an excel or text file, and when run, it shows who is supposed to be in that grid space for the day and can be updated daily within the excel file.
This is the code that I have/found but I want to connect this GUI to an excel file.
Thanks in advance for your attention!

```
from tkinter import *

class Cell():
    FILLED_COLOR_BG = "green"
    EMPTY_COLOR_BG = "white"
    FILLED_COLOR_BORDER = "green"
    EMPTY_COLOR_BORDER = "black"

def __init__(self, master, x, y, size):
    self.master = master
    self.abs = x
    self.ord = y
    self.size= size
    self.fill= False

def _switch(self):
    self.fill= not self.fill

def draw(self):
    if self.master != None :
        fill = Cell.FILLED_COLOR_BG
        outline = Cell.FILLED_COLOR_BORDER

        if not self.fill:
            fill = Cell.EMPTY_COLOR_BG
            outline = Cell.EMPTY_COLOR_BORDER

        xmin = self.abs * self.size
        xmax = xmin + self.size
        ymin = self.ord * self.size
        ymax = ymin + self.size

        self.master.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill = fill, outline = outline)

class CellGrid(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,master, rowNumber, columnNumber, cellSize, *args, **kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, width = cellSize * columnNumber , height = cellSize * rowNumber, *args, **kwargs)

    self.cellSize = cellSize

    self.grid = []
    for row in range(rowNumber):

        line = []
        for column in range(columnNumber):
            line.append(Cell(self, column, row, cellSize))

        self.grid.append(line)

   
    self.switched = []

   
    self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: self.switched.clear())

    self.draw()



def draw(self):
    for row in self.grid:
        for cell in row:
            cell.draw()

def _eventCoords(self, event):
    row = int(event.y / self.cellSize)
    column = int(event.x / self.cellSize)
    return row, column

def handleMouseClick(self, event):
    row, column = self._eventCoords(event)
    cell = self.grid[row][column]
    cell._switch()
    cell.draw()
    self.switched.append(cell)

def handleMouseMotion(self, event):
    row, column = self._eventCoords(event)
    cell = self.grid[row][column]

    if cell not in self.switched:
        cell._switch()
        cell.draw()
        self.switched.append(cell)


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = Tk()

    grid = CellGrid(app, 5, 2, 100)
    grid.pack()

    app.mainloop()
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.handleMouseClick)
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.handleMouseMotion)
```

Comment: I think this question is way too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: What would you recommend for me to be more specific?:s

Comment: What is the specific problem that you're having? Do you know how to read an excel file? Do you know how to insert data into a widget? Are you wanting us to explain how the code you found works? What is the main part of the problem you don't understand?